# Clojure extracting value from map based on prioritized logic

Tags: dictionary, filter, clojure, conditional-statements

I have a function that wants to pull a value out of a map based on a prioritized order.  Currently I'm doing it as a nested if structure which is horrible.  I have to believe there is a better way.

While this works is there a better way?

```
(defn filter-relatives [relatives]
    (if(contains? relatives :self)
         (relatives :self)
             (if(contains? relatives :north)
                 (relatives :north)
                     (if(contains? relatives :west)
                         (relatives :west)
                         (if(contains? relatives :east)
                             (relatives :east)
                             (relatives :south)
                         )
                     )
                 )
              )
          )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(some relatives [:self :north :west :east :south])
```

Comment: ...unless you also want to fetch nil values.

Comment: ...or `false`. If it is an issue, see my answer for an appropriate adjustment, otherwise definitely use this one.

Comment: As a general rule, we should provide the simplest idiomatic clojure code that solves the question asked.  Edge cases can be dealt with subsequently.  Being "clever" is likely to lead to the inexperienced developing bad habits by hiding better, more general solutions.

Comment: Well, sure, but who says otherwise? (If you were under the impression that I somehow did, please note the "otherwise definitely use this one" part of my comment above, as well as the first sentence of my answer.) In this particular case, the likely better solution (namely this one) is *not* the more general one, so I'd say it's best to point out its limitations, lest one leads inexperienced developers to using it without taking those limitations into account, perhaps in a situation where those actually matter.

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```
(defn filter-relatives [relatives ordered-filters] 
    (first (filter identity (map relatives ordered-filters))))
```

Sample run:

```
user=> (filter-relatives {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} [:z :b :a])                                                               
2
```

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are fine if `nil` and `false` are not among the possible values. If they are, you could use something like

```
(if-let [e (some (partial find relatives)
                 [:self :north :west :east :south])]
  (val e)
  :no-key-found)
```

E.g.

```
(if-let [e (some (partial find relatives)
                 [:self :north :west :east :south])]
  (val e)
  :no-key-found)
; => false

(if-let [e (some (partial find {})
                 [:self :north :west :east :south])]
  (val e)
  :no-key-found)
; => :no-key-found
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(first (keep relatives [:self :north :west :east :south]))
```